# LVM Encrypted Partition without Partition Table

Tags: linux-mint, partition, lvm, encryption, disk-encryption

I have the following Problem. My Laptop is fully encrypted with LVM I know the Passphrase, but the partition table is broken. I booted from an USB Stick in this Case sdb1. Is there any hope to get /dev/sda2 working again? sda1 ist mountable If I try to boot I will fall into initframs with no Volumne Groups found.

System is a Linux Mint Qiana.

```
 sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ca01e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   976771071   488134657    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 31.9 GB, 31910264832 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3879 cylinders, total 62324736 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00023cc3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    62324735    31161344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Thanks for any help

**EDIT 1: Testdisk log file after analyses and Deeper Search**

```
Analyse Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63
Geometry from i386 MBR: head=255 sector=63
Current partition structure:
 1 * Linux                    0  32 33    31  26 59     497664
 2 E extended                31  59 27 60801  47 46  976269314

search_part()
Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/30, s_mnt_count=36/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 33    31  26 59     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

     Linux                   31  59 29    31 124 29       4096
     LUKS 1 (Data size unknown), 2097 KB / 2048 KiB

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/974, s_mnt_count=1/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 31929088
recover_EXT2: part_size 255432704
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB

Results
   * Linux                    0  32 33    31  26 59     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB
   P Linux                   31  59 29    31 124 29       4096
     LUKS 1 (Data size unknown), 2097 KB / 2048 KiB
   P Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB

interface_write()
 1 * Linux                    0  32 33    31  26 59     497664
 2 P Linux                   31  59 29    31 124 29       4096
 3 P Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]

search_part()
Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/30, s_mnt_count=36/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 33    31  26 59     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 1

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 8193 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=1/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 3

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 24577 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=3/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 5

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 40961 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=5/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 7

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 57345 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=7/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 9

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 73729 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=9/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 25

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 204801 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=25/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

block_group_nr 27

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 221185 -B 1024 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=27/30, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=8192, s_inodes_per_group=2008
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=1024
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 248832
recover_EXT2: part_size 497664
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB

     Linux                   31  59 29    31 124 29       4096
     LUKS 1 (Data size unknown), 2097 KB / 2048 KiB

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/974, s_mnt_count=1/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 31929088
recover_EXT2: part_size 255432704
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB

block_group_nr 3

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 98304 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=3/4, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=7040
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 140800
recover_EXT2: part_size 1126400
     Linux                44085  57  5 44155  86 27    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB

block_group_nr 3

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 98304 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=3/5, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=6944
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 166400
recover_EXT2: part_size 1331200
     Linux                45394 183 38 45477 148 47    1331200
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 681 MB / 650 MiB

block_group_nr 3

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 98304 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=3/4, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=7040
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 140800
recover_EXT2: part_size 1126400
     Linux                45650 179 34 45720 208 56    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB

block_group_nr 1

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 32768 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=1/4, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=7040
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 140800
recover_EXT2: part_size 1126400
     Linux                46119 213 47 46189 243  6    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB

block_group_nr 3

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 98304 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=3/4, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=7040
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 140800
recover_EXT2: part_size 1126400
     Linux                46124 239  4 46195  13 26    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB

block_group_nr 243

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 7962624 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=243/974, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 31929088
recover_EXT2: part_size 255432704
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB

block_group_nr 343

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 11239424 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=343/974, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 31929088
recover_EXT2: part_size 255432704
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB

block_group_nr 625

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 20480000 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=625/974, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 31929088
recover_EXT2: part_size 255432704
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB

block_group_nr 729

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 23887872 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=729/974, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 31929088
recover_EXT2: part_size 255432704
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB
     Linux Swap           56031 145 51 56523 166 11    7905264
     SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 4047 MB / 3859 MiB

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/225, s_mnt_count=8/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Recover, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 3

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 98304 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=3/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 5

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 163840 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=5/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 7

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 229376 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=7/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 9

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 294912 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=9/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 25

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 819200 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=25/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 27

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 884736 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=27/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 49

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 1605632 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=49/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB

block_group_nr 125

recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 4096000 -B 4096 device" may be needed
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=125/225, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8208
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 7372800
recover_EXT2: part_size 58982400
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 30 GB / 28 GiB
     Linux Swap           58748  54 59 60801  47 30   32980976
     SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 16 GB / 15 GiB
     Linux Swap           59566  68 23 60801  47 30   19838960
     SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 10157 MB / 9686 MiB
NTFS at 60801/80/15
filesystem size           488386560
sectors_per_cluster       8
mft_lcn                   4
mftmirr_lcn               30524159
clusters_per_mft_record   -10
clusters_per_index_record 1
     HPFS - NTFS          30400 167 40 60801  80 15  488386560
     NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=4096, 250 GB / 232 GiB

Results
     Linux                    0  32 31    31  26 57     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB
     Linux                    0  32 33    31  26 59     497664
     ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB
   * Linux                   31  59 29    31 124 29       4096
     LUKS 1 (Data size unknown), 2097 KB / 2048 KiB
     HPFS - NTFS          30400 167 40 60801  80 15  488386560
     NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=4096, 250 GB / 232 GiB
     Linux                43874 158 61 59774 146 20  255432704 [kali]
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock, 130 GB / 121 GiB
     Linux                44085  57  5 44155  86 27    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB
     Linux                45394 183 38 45477 148 47    1331200
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 681 MB / 650 MiB
     Linux                45650 179 34 45720 208 56    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB
     Linux                46119 213 47 46189 243  6    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB
     Linux                46124 239  4 46195  13 26    1126400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 576 MB / 550 MiB
     Linux Swap           56031 145 51 56523 166 27    7905280
     SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 4047 MB / 3860 MiB
     Linux                56523 166 28 60195  34 63   58982400
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Recover, 30 GB / 28 GiB
     Linux Swap           58748  54 59 60801  47 46   32980992
     SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 16 GB / 15 GiB
     Linux Swap           59566  68 23 60801  47 46   19838976
     SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 10157 MB / 9687 MiB

interface_write()
 1 * Linux                   31  59 29    31 124 29       4096
simulate write!

write_mbr_i386: starting...
write_all_log_i386: starting...
No extended partition

TestDisk exited normally.
```

[image: Gparted Screenshot]

[image: Testdisk Analyse Screenshot]

[image: Testdisk Deep Analyse Screenshot]

I don't remember that I haved kali installed at any time ;-) maybe just the name i gave my machine at the beginning (i played a lot around -.-) As you can see, sda2 is where my data was. But also the Swap which was around 4 GB. DHEX analyses of the image file will follow.

**EDIT 2: Additional information**

While I was waiting on dhex I searched the web, here is what i got.

[Forum entry with the same Problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643334)

My Hexdump so far.

```
sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda1 | grep LUKS
0052cd90  73 73 20 64 65 6e 69 65  64 00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be  |ss denied.LUKS..|
0e2a5190  73 73 20 64 65 6e 69 65  64 00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be  |ss denied.LUKS..|
0ea31590  73 73 20 64 65 6e 69 65  64 00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be  |ss denied.LUKS..|

sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda | grep LUKS
0052cd90  73 73 20 64 65 6e 69 65  64 00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be  |ss denied.LUKS..|
0e2a5190  73 73 20 64 65 6e 69 65  64 00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be  |ss denied.LUKS..|
0ea31590  73 73 20 64 65 6e 69 65  64 00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be  |ss denied.LUKS..|
------------- so here must be sda2 -----------------------------------------
0f500000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
94c5c010  00 00 00 00 00 63 72 79  70 74 6f 5f 4c 55 4b 53  |.....crypto_LUKS|
94c5c020  00 4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00  68 70 74 33 37 78 5f 72  |.LUKS...hpt37x_r|
29298a430  f2 4c 55 4b 53 25 ab 35  c5 6a 27 d5 47 e7 8e a2  |.LUKS%.5.j'.G...|
```

Following the instruction on this post I made the following.

```
mint@mint /mnt $ sudo losetup -o 0xf500000 -r -f /dev/sda
mint@mint /mnt $ sudo losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [0005]:7471 (/dev/sda), offset 256901120
mint@mint /mnt $ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 luksrecover
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda: (input was correct YEAH)
mint@mint /mnt $ sudo mount -o ro /dev/mapper/luksrecover /mnt/recover
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

so what is wrong?

I saw the 491 GB device and try to mount it via nemo. Here is the Error.

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/dm-1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/49874409-67ff-421f-b544-1d86f801081a"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Here is what dmesg | tail gives

```
[89128.037568] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-1
[89128.037579] Buffer I/O error on device dm-1, logical block 12
[89128.037580] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-1
[89128.037596] Buffer I/O error on device dm-1, logical block 13
[89128.037597] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-1
[89128.037609] Buffer I/O error on device dm-1, logical block 17
[89128.037610] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-1
[89128.057864] JBD2: recovery failed
[89128.057870] EXT4-fs (dm-1): error loading journal
[89794.733462] EXT4-fs (dm-1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
```

**EDIT 3: Adding lvdisplay information**

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/mint-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                mint-vg
  LV UUID                Jijx24-cBN8-lQ6P-Kgbx-tnQD-pYLf-7u8Wf7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time mint, 2014-11-23 13:17:01 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                457.61 GiB
  Current LE             117148
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/mint-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                mint-vg
  LV UUID                tDumHJ-mUAF-eXVk-V00W-HWWp-RWIL-YCNsVL
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time mint, 2014-11-23 13:17:02 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                7.86 GiB
  Current LE             2013
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2
```

Comment: How did the partition table get destroyed?

Comment: What partitions are you supposed to have?

Comment: @derobert I think i deleted the partition table with gparted when i was a little distracted ... schame on me

Comment: @Graeme I only have a partition which boots and asked for the passphrase to unlock and moutn the other partition sda2

Comment: @SvenBamberger Ah, then that at least probably didn't destroy any data, so it should be possible to get it back. I'm not sure if `testdisk` can find LUKS headers. Basically, you want to find where the partition started by looking for the LUKS magic number `LUKS\xba\xbe`

Comment: @derobert what do you mean with `LUKS\xba\xbe` ? I'm not that familiar with LUKS

Comment: If you know that `sda1` is correct and `sda2` just uses the of the disk, you could try deleting and recreating `sda2` with `fdisk`. Make sure to back up first though.

Comment: @SvenBamberger A LUKS partition starts with the ASCII characters `LUKS` followed by the bytes given in hexadecimal as `0xBA`, `0xBE`. Those 6 bytes start all LUKS partitions (and hopefully nothing else)... so if you find them, that's where your partition started. You could use a hex-dump too (e.g., `xxd`) to look for them by hand, or maybe testdisk can do it. Then recreate sda2 so it starts with that sector.

Comment: @derobert how do I use testdisk to find something? I never used it before.

So i should first make a dd image from the harddrive to an external hdd  and work on that?

Comment: @SvenBamberger Pretty much you run it as `testdisk /dev/sda`... It will hopefully tell you where the LUKS partition began. Note that if you have it write a new partition table, it'll use the minimum length (which is wrong, but the LUKS header doesn't store the length). Instead I'd take the offset and use fdisk/sfdisk to put the partition entry back in place. BTW: Taking a full image of the drive before attempting recovery is recommended, just in case...

Comment: (and yeah, normally I'd write up step-by-step directions... but no time at the moment. I'm hoping someone else will!)

Comment: @derobert then i first start to make an image and the start working an the hdd I will write again when I tried what you said.

Comment: @derobert I added a lot more information. Maybe it will help

Comment: The device you want to mount is `/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root`. You made your loop device read-only, so when the filesystem attempted journal recovery on mount it failed. The mount manpage tells me `mount -o ro,noload /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root /media/whatever` ought to avoid that problem.

Comment: @derobert where can i spend you a beer? you saved my weekend ^^. Just one more thing, is it possible to recreate the partition table I deleted?

Comment: @SvenBamberger Save the beer money and send it to a worthy cause. You can recreate the partition table with that offset you discovered. If the LUKS partition is the only other partition on the disk, you just need to create a partition starting at that offset/512 (512 being the size of one sector) and ending at the end of the disk. `sfdisk` can do that, or `fdisk`, or any number of other partition editors. If there were more partitions, the process is similar, except you need to use more of those offsets from testdisk.