# Recovering a LUKS partition

Tags: partition, data-recovery, luks

I have a drive with 2 partitions

- 1st is plain ext4
- 2nd is encrypted LUKS.

The partition table has been overwritten. I've found the beginning of the second partition, which I need to recover, thusly:

```
# hexdump -s 400000m -C /dev/sdc | grep LUKS
61d3dec850 79 c8 81 6d e5 4c 55 4b 53 40 49 aa 29 df de d7 |y..m.LUKS@I.)...|
```

Also:

```
# losetup -o 0x61d3dec850 -r -f /dev/sdc
# losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0005]:477209 (/dev/sdc), offset 420166420560
```

So far, this problem pops up:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 luksrecover
Device /dev/loop0 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Is it wrong offset? Should I seek for the magic number `0xEF53` identifying ext4 [as adviced here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/how-do-i-find-the-offset-of-an-ext4-filesystem) ?

It's a 1TB drive so please, I need an advice that does not force a scan of the entire drive all over again (e.g. `testdisk` which seems have no option to start at a specified offset to save time on scanning).

P.S. [This question seems to be closely related but does not match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177070/lvm-encrypted-partition-without-partition-table).

Comment: Just a idea from binary logic: did you may have missed the offset by one bit?

Comment: How would that happen? I suspect it's more likely a false positive on LUKS finding as already has been suggested here http://serverfault.com/questions/656752/luks-partition-recovery#656768 . I recall experimenting with cryptsetup on this drive prior to the final implementation and it could be remnants of that. I'll keep seeking for more LUKS hits.

Comment: I wish happy hunting (But thanks for the remainder to backup the header data / partition table)

Comment: Indeed, indeed. I have the LUKS headers saved , but not the partition table. Lesson learned.

Comment: If you have a backup of the header (a real backup, which is usually >1MB in size, not just a luksDump), recovery is possible. Same if you actually find the real header intact. What you showed is not a LUKS header.

Answer (score 3):

```
dd if=/dev/mapper/storage2-crypto bs=16 count=1 2>/dev/null | 
  od -t c -t x1
0000000   L   U   K   S 272 276  \0 001   a   e   s  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
         4c  55  4b  53  ba  be  00  01  61  65  73  00  00  00  00  00
```

That's what it looks like on my system. See https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf (page 6)

The first six bytes must be the same, most probably the first eight and probably the first 16+. You have found a string with `LUKS` but obviously the wrong one as `LUKS@I` is not the magic bytes.

Look for the right data; that should give you the correct position.