# Rebuild LUKS as extended container

Tags: partition, encryption, luks

I deleted a [LUKS](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/) partition by [fdisk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk) for some reason; I rebuilt it, but mistakenly did so as an extended container, then hit `w`.

Although I deleted the extended container later, and rebuilt the [LUKS](https://guardianproject.info/code/luks/) (/dev/sda4) again. However, 'hexdump /dev/sda4 | less'  shows that the address before 00000260 contains nearly no printable characters (except dots and an 'U').  Starting from 00000260 are some random characters.

Is it rebuilding [LUKS](https://guardianproject.info/code/luks/) as an extended container because the header was damaged?

Comment: Can you still decrypt the container? Find the luks "magic bytes"? Have a header backup?

Comment: No, no backup. After learning, know that before computer reaches the quantum power, I will give up rescue of my LUKS without header.

So I'm going to create a new Luks, is LUKS2 a better choice because I hear it stores multiple backups of LUKS2 header?

Comment: I haven't read about LUKS2 yet, but it's most likely an improvement. Anyway, re-partitioning alone might not have overwritten anything, but reformatting could have... luks's "magic bytes" are basically just LUKS ('L','U','K','S', 0xba, 0xbe according to [the faq](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)) recovering the header might still be possible, or see other Q's [like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177831/recovering-a-luks-partition). Also, if you had made a backup of just the master key it would be very useful, it's only about 50 chars

Answer (score 2):

If this is related to [your earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509369/do-my-luks-partition-damaged), then yes: setting up an extended partition includes writing an Extended Partition Boot Record (EPBR or sometimes EBR) at the very beginning of the extended partition. [Wikipedia has a description of it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record)

The EPBR would be written exactly where the LUKS header would be, so yes, it would cause the LUKS header to be overwritten.

Comment: May the logical partition be a danger in re-numbering partition? Is GPT doesn't has logical partition the better choice than MBR?

Comment: If the LUKS partition gets renumbered, **it can be fixed**: just boot in rescue mode/end up in single user shell because normal boot failed, use `cryptsetup luksOpen` manually with the new partition number, mount your filesystems, chroot to your real root filesystem if necessary, and then edit the new partition number into `/etc/crypttab` and rebuild your initramfs. The partition number may change, but as long as the `cryptsetup` gets the right parameters, LUKS does not care. But as you discovered, overwriting the LUKS header is **not fixable** unless you have a backup of it.